# Pymongo:iterating dictionary of a list of dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let us say I have a big collection including documents such as these:

```
{"_id": 0, 
"name":"John Doe",
"items": [
     {"x":5,
      "y":8,
      "z":9},
     {"x":4,
      "y":2,
      "z":1},
     {"x":3,
      "y":5,
      "z":8}
]
}
```

I am fetching the collection into a variable called 'data' with pymongo and trying to iterate over the items in order to update some. I have tried to print those values with the following code:

```
for i in data:
    for j in data[i].get("items"):
        pprint(j.get("x"))
```

and it gave an error:

```
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query
```

Even if I get the items, I do not see a way to change data. Why is this happening and how can I iterate through items and change their values?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you mean by "a way to change data". Please give an example of the document before and after modification that you need. Also your loop looks wrong: `for i in data: for j in data[i]...`. What is `data` and how do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How looks db query?

Try something like this for iteration:

```
cursor = db.get_collection('some_collection').find()

for doc in cursor:
    for item in doc['items']:
        pprint(item.get('x'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you want to change the values of all `x`.

```
for i in data.get('items'):
    # to change the values in items
    # this will replace all values of key x
    i['x'] = new_value
```

simply assign a new value to `items` key.